# Strapi Homepage request with array of items and their details

Tags: strapi

I am trying to set up a Strapi deployment to provide an API for my website.

I am attempting to display a list of brands and their logos on the home page.

I have tried two routes:

1. Create a brand collection type, then a single collection "homepage" and add a relational field to that containing the brands
2. Create a brand component, then a single collection "homepage" and add the component in

In both these cases, I cannot do an API call to get the list of brands and their images. If I do `/homepage` I get just the homepage (no brands at all).

If I do `/homepage?populate=*` I get the array of brands, but no images

I feel this should be quite a standard strapi request - retrieve a homepage of data and render it, but I am struggling to work out how to do it.